# Dropbox Android API sample project won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, import, dropbox-api

I've download the [Dropbox Android API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases), unpacked the sample project and opened it in Eclipse. However it has trouble with importing the API:

```
import com.dropbox.client.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client.DropboxAPI.Config;
```

it can't find it. I have `dropbox-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the lib folder of my project, which is where I assume these classes are, but it can't access them. What do I need to do to get up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed this, I needed to add the jars to the Java Build Path in the Project's Properties.